# How can I convert a digraph to an undirected graph in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using the networkx package. Is there a function in networkx which can do the task for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the function 
http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.to_undirected.html?highlight=digraph

Comment: This does not work for me. The input graph has two copies of each edge, one in each direction, and I would like to have a graph with the same amount of edges but traversable in both directioned. This function does not seem to allow for that as regardless of what I set "reciprocal" to in this call DiGraph.to_undirected(reciprocal=False) the number of edges in my graph always halves. Any suggestions on how to get around that? I would like the same amount of edges, but for them to be undirected. Thanks

Comment: @AlexAverbuch - i suspect this is not useful anymore, but if it is - you can't have multiple undirected edges between the same two nodes, one undirected edge accomplishes the same thing (that's why it's 'undirected'). the regular `Graph` object can't even represent what you want, afaik. but you should ask that as a new question if still something you need answered.